# rails hash extract first value from list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to normalize some data in an ETL process because the data we get is not consistent.

Annoying but i am here to learn.

currently we do something like:

```
received = datum[:quantity_received] || datum[:received_cases] || datum[:received_quantity]
```

Curious if there is a more ruby/rails way of doing this?

considering:

```
received = datum.values_at(:quantity_received,:received_cases,:received_quantity).compact.first
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a much better solution. I'd try to define some helper methods (I'm not a long lines' supporter)

```
def value_you_need(datum)
  datum.values_at(*keys_of_interest).find(&:itself)
end

def keys_of_interest
  %i(quantity_received received_cases received_quantity)
end

received = value_you_need(datum)
```

`object#itself` method is present from ruby 2.2.0. Otherwise, go for `compact.first`.

Note a detail: if `false` is one of the values you care about the solution with `compact.first` is the only one correct of our three. But I took for granted you don't or the first option would be wrong.